# ¿Por que no me reproduce mi Audio en Android compilado con Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova

**Mi proyecto esta realizado con Javascript y compilado con Cordova.** 
Estoy utilizando un tag de audio, donde le doy la ruta de mi archivo mp3.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa en la imagen.. el primer tag me reproduce el audio de manera correcta., pero el segundo no me encuentra. Ahora la respuesta es que no me interpreta los acentos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa, el primer tag audio, si reproduce y aparece su duracion de la misma, pero en la segunda opcion no aparece su duracion ni tampoco lo reproduce.... tampoco me sale ningun tipo de error en la consola... al momento de realizar el debug respectivo.

Comment: Intenta modificar el `path` al segundo audio ya que posiblemente el problema se de por el **espacio y los acentos** del directorio `Módulo Presentación`

Comment: Intente hacerlo, cuando ya no presentan acentos y/o espacios ya funciona correctamente, pero el dilema es que esos directorios siempre tendrán acentos y/o espacios. Sera alguna configuración que se realiza dentro del cordova o algun plugin???

Comment: Pudiste solucionar el problema? Mi respuesta te fue de ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es como esta escrito el `path` al segundo archivo.

Una solución es escribir el `path` a los recursos en [formato `URL`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Es decir:

```
<audio src="recursos/Módulo Presentación/Archivos/PresentacionSWF/2CARACTER2/2caracter21.mp3" controls/>
```

Deberías escribirlo así:

```
<audio src="recursos/M%C3%B3dulo%20Presentaci%C3%B3n/Archivos/PresentacionSWF/2CARACTER2/2caracter21.mp3" controls/>
```

Ejemplo usando `JS`

```js
document.getElementById('encode').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('output').value = 
    encodeURI(document.getElementById('url').value);
});
```

```html
URL: <input id="url" value="recursos/Módulo Presentación/Archivos/PresentacionSWF/2CARACTER2/2caracter21.mp3"/>
<button id="encode">Encode</button><br/>

URL encode: <input id="output"/>
```

Comment: Saludos estilado @MarcosGallardo, el problema era el siguiente no era necesario realizar el encodeURI. El motivo era que no estaba contemplando la ruta correcta.